# Magento non www to www and http to https .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, web, https

The below works fine but I get a redirects warning if `http://mysite` or `https://` is used `https://www.mysite` works fine.

In magento admin I have Auto-redirect to Base URL set to yes (301 moved permanently) .

What do I use for making Magento work work correctly with non www and https in one simple instruction
My base url is `https://www.mysite`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder if you know about https://magento.stackexchange.com where there are already several questions about htaccess redirecting from non-www to www? You may find the answer you seek already posted there.

Comment: Thanks I have read a lot on the subject but I am not super technical. There are so many solutions. The one I am using is fine for now thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you that works though I still need to use the redirect built into magento (Auto-redirect to Base URL) set to 301, thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Pleace accept answer if it fits for your needs :)

Comment: I use this version eventually.                                                          RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]